# .NET 5 application insights is not showing my exception stack trace?

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I have a .NET 5 web application and I have configured application insights.
When an error is thrown in my application I can see it in the azure portal, but I don't see any stacktrace

[image]

I installed both nuget packages:
[image]

In my startup:

```
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

I even tried to configure logging in my program.cs as described [here](https://dev.to/luturol/how-to-configure-azure-applications-insights-on-net-5-7a3)

```
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.AddApplicationInsights();
                logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>(string.Empty, LogLevel.Trace);
            })
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it shown when you follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions#reporting-exceptions-explicitly)?

Comment: @mu88 When using new Telemetry() I get an obsolete warning. We do not recommend using TelemetryConfiguration.Active on .NET Core. See https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1152 for more details

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I'm still fiddling around with this a bit, but according to docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions#web-api)
"**All exceptions handled by application still need to be tracked manually.**"

Which means that if you write your own exception handlers, you still have to send the exception and stacktrace to application insights yourself.

For example

Either throw the original exception

```
catch (Exception e)
{
  throw;
}
```

Or send the exception yourself using Ilogger and LogError:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    _logger.LogError(e, "message here");
    return BadRequest(e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Do you have an exception middleware? It could send the exceptions to Application Insights as a central piece of code